# How to use "." as pattern in stringr::str_split() function

Tags: r, stringr, strsplit

I'm trying to split a string containing "."

### For example :
"Who.am.I?"

"Who", "am", "I?"

In a similar attempt, it succeeded in splitting characters by "&" by using stringr::str_split()
For example:

```
stringr::str_split("Who&am&I?", pattern="&")
[[1]]
[1] "Who" "am" "I?"
```

It can be divided like this.

However, changing & to. yields the following results

```
stringr::str_split("Who.am.I?", pattern=".")
[[1]]
[1] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

1. Why return this kind of output?
2. Is there a way to use "." as a pattern?
   Could you tell us about the above two points?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Tokunaga

Comment: use fixed(".").

Comment: See the linked question and answers. By default `pattern` is a regular expression, and "." means "match any character", unless you escape it or use fixed.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your kind response.
I understand it very well now.

Comment: Thanks to your advice I got the following result

stringr::str_split("Who.am.I?", pattern="\\.")
[[1]]
[1] "Who" "am" "I?"